# Call sub orchestrator within a sub orchestrator

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I’m trying to learn about durable functions. Is it possible to call a sub orchestrator function within a sub orchestrator function?

```
Orchestrator:

[FunctionName(nameof(OrchestratorFunction))]
        public async Task RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
     
              var syncJobs = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<SyncJob>>(nameof(SyncJobsReaderFunction), null);
              if (syncJobs != null && syncJobs.Count > 0)
              {
                // Run multiple sync job processing flows in parallel
                var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var syncJob in syncJobs)
                {                    
                    var processTask = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(SubOrchestratorFunction1), syncJob);
                    processingTasks.Add(processTask);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
            }            
        }


SubOrchestrator:

[FunctionName(nameof(SubOrchestratorFunction1))]
        public async Task RunSubOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
                var syncJob = context.GetInput<SyncJob>();           
                // Run multiple query processing flows in parallel
                var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var query in syncJob.queries)
                {                    
                    var processTask = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(SubOrchestratorFunction2), query);
                    processingTasks.Add(processTask);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible. To quote the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sub-orchestrations?tabs=csharp)

> Sub-orchestrator functions behave just like activity functions from the caller's perspective. They can return a value, throw an exception, and can be awaited by the parent orchestrator function.